# gcc -Wl,--defsym on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, gcc, ld

Under Linux I can issue a

```
gcc -Wl,--defsym,main=main_x ..
```

However in Mac OSX 10 I get an error

```
ld: unknown option: --defsym
```

Does anyone know an switch for Mac's gcc that is similar to --defsym ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-alias` is the closest equivalent I could find:

```
-Wl,-alias,_main,_main_x
```

Note that it uses "raw" symbol names, so you have to prefix everything with an underscore.

Comment: -alias was the option I searched for, thanks. I was trying it before but didn't know about the _.

Answer (score 0):

Does OSX use the gnu linker? I don't think it does. gcc's man page says defsym likely only works with the gnu linker:

```
-Wl,--defsym,__stack_limit=0x7ffe0000 to enforce a stack limit of 128KB. Note that this may only work with the GNU linker.
```

I've also seen [makefiles](http://ftd4linux.nl/svn/nntpgrab/tags/nntpgrab-0.4.90/client/gui/Makefile.am) that show the OSX linker does not do defsym. Notice the 'if DARWIN' section of that makefile.

Comment: "-alias" was the option I seached for (see duskwuff's answer)